# How to disable Save As button in MS Project VBA?

Tags: .net, vba, ms-project, save-as

How can I disable the just the "Save As" Button for MS Project and keep the "Save" button enabled ?

Comment: You want to do this in a specific sheet only and not for all users of MS Project on that PC right?

Comment: It will be applied to all the projects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 options then:

1) Disable the saveas dialog in windows on each machine for MS Project using group policies. If you want thsi option, let me know the version of Office that is on the machines. Or you can dig it up yourself. You need a document like [this one for MS Office 2007](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3582) to give you the IDs to modify in group policies.

2) Put VBA code in each. Since you tagged it VBA, I assume this is the preferred approach though the first could be added to the build process for the company, it wouldn't follow the sheet onto an external machine if you shared it with contractors or consultants. So, assuming you want the second this should work for you. I don't have MS Project on this PC so I can't test it but I think I have the syntax correct for you. Set it up as a trigger.

```
Public Sub Project_BeforeSave(ByVal pj As Project, ByVal SaveAsUi As Boolean, Info As EventInfo)
         If SaveAsUI = True Then Info.Cancel = True
End Sub
```

Give a shout if that doesn't do it for you :-) Also let me know what version of MS Project you are using, just to be safe. I don't think it will matter though.